# Unequal values in dataframe after merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am taking an introductory course to data sciences and I have this assignment where I have to merge 3 datasets indexed by the country name. The shape of the resultant dataframe that I have coded is the same as the one required but I am getting a failure on equality testing. An error is received which reads:

Iterating through the dataframes we found that there were differences in the following columns: dict_keys(['Energy Supply per Capita', 'Energy Supply']).

I checked and compared values of both these columns from my resultant dataframe and the original dataframe from where these values were merged, the values were equal in both cases. 
What might I be missing here?

Comment: please give us samples of all the data frames otherwise we can not help you

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the data types? if you imported them differently they might have imported as an object from one source and an int from another.

you can check dtype by printing

```
df['col_name'].dtype
```

really there's not a lot to go on in your question I'm afraid.

Comment: I have converted all the datatypes to the required dtype using astype. Let me share some sample code.